# Change Overall Look and Feel/Color Of A ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, combobox, controls

I am writing a GUI form application in C# using Visual Studio 2010. The overall look and feel of my app is black.

I have added a few ComboBoxes to my form but they look terrible because the color is light grey. I want to make the combo box black. (Not the background/foreground color of the items themselves but rather the color of the combo box itself.)

How can I make a ComboBox black? An added bonus would be if I could make the corners of the combo box round instead of square so if you know how to do that it would be helpful too!

Thanks!

Comment: what framework, winforms or WPF

Comment: This is where WPF was introduced! :)

Comment: This will be a rather tricky task in winforms, if your looking at a themed GUI you may want to consider swtching to a different framework that supports this type of thing a bit better.

Comment: I am embarrased to say this but I don't even know the difference between winforms and WPF. :( I am a Java developer but my current project requires C#. Anyone care to elaborate on the difference? Thanks!